# questions on the hack architecture

Tags: architecture

The hack architecture is a 16 bit computer. modern say processors are 32 bit or 64 bit

suggest two potential impacts of changing the hack architecture from 16 bits to 32 bits

what changes would be needed to make the hack architecture from 16 bit to 32 bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 32 bits you can encode more instructions and transfer more data in a single instruction.

To change your architecture, you need to:

- change your registers and the buses.
- change the alu range.
- add logic for ram manipulation. (because the ram mus have 8bit cells and your processor works with 32 bit instructions)

And because you have 32 bits you can encode more instructions like multiply, divide, etc.